# Google+ api returns broken profile link

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-signin

We use googleplus api in our project, so user can link his account. Then we display a link retreived from https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo endpoint (field "link"), but we start getting links that leads to 404 page. Link shape looks like every other valid link. https://plus.google.com/USER_ID

Answer (score 0):

Not all Google accounts have Google+ profiles.

Comment: API have provided that link - if there is no account , API should not provide it - am I wrong ?

Comment: I'm sure Google's plan was everyone would have a Google+ profile but that didn't really work out like they wanted.